# Qt-Creator cross compile for Raspberry Pi

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I'm looking for a way to cross-compile my C++ project in Qt-Creator. I have the arm-gcc set up and ready, but i cannot figure out how to setup the right kit for building in qt-creator.

Does anyone have a working kit config for that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To build a custom kit for cross-compilation in Qt Creator, you have to have the toolchain (which you have) and a cross compiled Qt library.

If you do not have a cross compiled Qt library, there's a [wiki article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide) to building Qt for Raspberry Pi. It also explains how to set up a kit.

To sum it up though in case those who are similarly confused.

Under Options > Build & Run > Compilers, add your toolchain by pointing by locating your arm-linux-gcc or similar compiler.

Then under Qt Versions tab, add the path to your cross-compiled qt library by locating the subseqent cross-compiled qmake binary.

Finally, you bring those items together under the Kits tab where you add a kit, name it, select your compiler well as your Qt version you added.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks! I already tried the those instructions but they fail for me. I also tried getting the scripts to work which are linked in the wiki article but they fail at the point where they try to execute ./configure in qtbase. Did you manage to build your cross-compiled sdk with those instructions?

Comment: I didn't use those instructions specifically as I don't use the raspbian images; however, the process is relatively similar. I think we need to take a step back since the current problem isn't Qt-Creator but cross-compilation of Qt. You may want to edit your question. First, what exactly is failing during the ./configure?

Comment: In the paragraph about building qtbase the guide (and the bakeqtpi scripts) tell me to run ./configure in qtbase, but qtbase here is just a patch file, not a directory. I don't really know how to continue since I probably can't just skip this essential step.

Comment: qtbase should exist as an empty directory after you clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git. Then you have to fetch the contents by executing ./init-repository. Optionally, you can download the tar source from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1.tar.gz.